# hi guys can any one help me

Tags: batch

If I create a record of `cumtomer_order__c` which are related to account object so rest of account which have aslo cutomer_order__c records automatically update last I am using Bacth class and Schelud class

```
//Batch class
global class orderBatchclass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

list<Account> AccList = new list<Account>();
list<Customer_order__c> oderList = new list<Customer_order__c>();
//start
global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext Bc){
    return DataBase.getQueryLocator('select id,name,Last_Order_Name__c,Last_Order_Date__c,Last_Order_Price__c,Last_Order_By_Name__c,Last_Order_Status__c,(select id,name__c,date__c,note__c,status__c,Number__c from Customer_orders__r order by createdDate desc ) from account');
}
//execute
global void execute(DataBase.BatchableContext bc, list<Account> Acclist){
    list<Account> newAccount = new list<Account>();
    Account accObj = new Account();
    for(Account acc : Acclist){    
        list<Customer_order__c> coList = new list<Customer_order__c>();
        integer count=0;
        accObj=new Account(id = acc.id);
        accObj.Last_3_Order__c='[';
        for(Customer_order__c con : acc.Customer_orders__r){
            if(con.Status__c == 'Delivered'){
                accObj.Last_3_Order__c+= con.Name__c == null?'': '\''+con.Name__c;
                accObj.Last_3_Order__c+= con.date__c == null ? '' : '\''+con.date__c+'\'';
                accObj.Last_3_Order__c+= con.Number__c == null? '' : '\''+con.Number__c;
                accObj.Last_3_Order__c+= con.Status__c == null? '' : '\''+con.Status__c;
                //accObj.Last_3_Order__c+=con.Name__c+'\''+con.Date__c+'\',\''+con.Number__c+'\',\''+con.Status__c;
                count++;
                if(count==3){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    accObj.Last_3_Order__c+='<br />';
                }
            } 
            coList.add(con);
        }//inner loop
        accObj.Last_3_Order__c+=']';
        if(coList.size()>0){
            accObj.Last_Order_Name__c = coList.get(0).Id;
            accObj.Last_Order_Date__c = coList.get(0).Date__c;
            accObj.Last_Order_Price__c = coList.get(0).Number__c;
            accObj.Last_Order_Status__c = coList.get(0).status__c;
            accObj.Last_Order_By_Name__c = UserInfo.getName();
        }
        if(acc.Customer_orders__r.size()>0){
            newAccount.add(accObj);
        }
     }
     if(newAccount.size()>0){
            update newAccount;
        } 

}
//Stop
global void finish(DataBase.BatchableContext bc){

}
}
```

---

```
//scheuld class

global class orderScheuldclass implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext Sc){
      orderBatchclass obj = new orderBatchclass();
      DataBase.executeBatch(obj,10);

     String sctimer = '0 59 * * * ?';//to set a time 
        sec,min,hour,day,month,year
     orderScheuldclass objOrderScheuldclass = new orderScheuldclass();
     system.Schedule('orderScheuldclass class 
     Run',sctimer,objOrderScheuldclass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the query in your batch class accordingly, which will query only one record of Account. For that you need to pass the account which you want to process.

If you need only one account to be processed, then I would suggest to pass it in the constructor of the batch class.

```
Account accRecord; //add this as a variable in your batch class.

//below constructor will assign the passed account to your above variable.
global orderBatchclass(Account acc){
      accRecord = acc;
}
```

Also change your query in the start method to mention the where clause:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext Bc){
    return DataBase.getQueryLocator('select id,name,Last_Order_Name__c,Last_Order_Date__c,Last_Order_Price__c,Last_Order_By_Name__c,Last_Order_Status__c,(select id,name__c,date__c,note__c,status__c,Number__c from Customer_orders__r order by createdDate desc ) from account where Id=\''+accRecord.id+'\'');
}
```

Once you do this, the scheduler class where you are calling this batch class from, you need to pass the account from there.

```
orderBatchclass obj = new orderBatchclass(acc); //You need to pass the account to be processed.
DataBase.executeBatch(obj,10);
```

It will help you in processing only one account record in batch class.